# CGAL::Intersection thread safe

Tags: cgal

I'm using 2D `CGAL::Intersection` via Cartesian kernel but it leads to `double free or corruption (fasttop)` error when i'm using it in parallel mode. Is there a way to call it from an object or is there a thread-safe version of this function ?

Can someone help me fix it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thread safety for handles and `CGAL::Exact_predicates_exact_constructions_kernel` will be added in CGAL 5.4.

For prior versions, you can use GMPXX and `CGAL::Simple_cartesian<mpq_class>` as Kernel type.